# Is this possible in scala def convert(f: () ⇒ Future[Int]): Future[() ⇒ Int] =?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future

```
def computeComplexNumber: () ⇒ Future[Int] =
  () ⇒
    Future {
      println("Computing complex number ...")
      Int.MaxValue
  }

def convert(f: () ⇒ Future[Int]): Future[() ⇒ Int] = ???

convert(computeComplexNumber)
```

Is it possible to implement `convert` method with above signature with condition that when `convert(computeComplexNumber)` is called, nothing gets printed unless you do this

```
Await.result(convert(computeComplexNumber), 5.seconds)()
```

Comment: Out of interest, why is the result `Future[() => Int]` not just `() => Int`? The function won't do anything until you call it (synchronously), so there doesn't seem to be any benefit it wrapping it in a `Future`. I guess there is a bigger picture here...

Answer (score 10):

I don't see any way to do it without blocking inside `convert`. There is simply no way to get hold of an instance of `Future[X]` inside of `convert`, without invoking `f`. But once you invoke `f`, the `Future { ... }` will eagerly start to evaluate the block with the `println`, and produce an output.

You probably want to take a look at `scalaz.concurrent.Task` instead.

Comment: It is possible to do this without blocking in `convert`.

Comment: Why is this incorrect answer being voted up so much? stackoverflow is a strange place...

Comment: @Tim Quote 1 ([comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711501/is-this-possible-in-scala-def-convertf-%e2%87%92-futureint-future-%e2%87%92-int/51711717#comment90403872_51711717)): *"It is possible to do this without blocking in convert"*; Quote 2: ([answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51721170/2707792)): `() => Await.result(f(), Duration.Inf)` inside `convert`. Am I missing anything? Is it the same `Tim`?

Comment: My point is that I provided a solution and you did not, and yet your answer is preferred over mine.

Comment: @Tim This might appear strange because you cannot see the mass grave that this thread actually is (need access to mod tools for that). There are now four deleted answers between 17 and 21 hours old. One of the deleted answers is by a really experienced user with >25k rep, who accidentally fell into [the same old trap](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3zofjl/why_is_future_totally_unusable/). I guess the 10 upvoters wanted to emphasize that constructs like Scalaz `Task` have been invented for a reason, and that there is no easy way to achieve the same with `Future`s.

Comment: @Tim `Future` just seems to be a somewhat lower-level construct that doesn't play well with side effects. I wouldn't call it "unusable" (as in in the somewhat provocatively titled linked discussion), `Future`s are perfectly fine as a basic building block for all kind of more powerful abstractions, but if you want to have more fine-grained control over side effects, you need something slightly more sophisticated.

Comment: I take the point about side-effects, and expecting the `println` to come out at any particular time is unreasonable. I had assumed that the `println` was just a trace call and that the real code was side-effect free. I think we can agree that the real problem here is the question, not the answers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert `() => Future[Int]` to `() => Int` you have to wait for the result of the `Future` like this:

```
def convert(f: () ⇒ Future[Int]): Future[() ⇒ Int] =
  Future{
    () => Await.result(f(), Duration.Inf)
  }
```

Then

```
val f = convert(computeComplexNumber) // Get Future
val g = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf) // Get Function
g() // Call function
```

The output will not appear until you call `g`.

---

### Explanation in response to comments

#### The question

At the core of this question is this function signature:

```
def convert(f: () ⇒ Future[Int]): Future[() ⇒ Int]
```

There is also a requirement that (in paraphrase)

> `f` is not invoked until the returned function is invoked

Also, I am assuming that the `Int` in the result is the value returned by the `Future` in the argument, not just some random number!

#### The issues

The return type of the input function is `Future[Int]` and the return type of the output function is `Int`. The first is an asynchronous result and the second is a synchronous result. Any solution must therefore convert from asynchronous `Future[Int]` to synchronous `Int`. This means `Await.result` or something similar.

There is also a requirement that the input function is not executed until the output function is executed. This means that it must be called *inside the returned function* which, in turn, means that the `Await.result` must be called inside the returned function.

#### The solution

The solution above has the function signature of `convert` that is required by the question. It also does not invoke `f` until the function returned by `convert` is executed, which was the other requirement.

This implementation of `convert` is not blocking; it returns immediately with a `Future` value. It does not invoke `f`, it just returns a function that does.

#### The comments

There is some dispute about what it means to block inside a function, or for one function to invoke another. Blocking and invoking are processes that that happen during the execution of a function. Therefore a sensible definition of these things happening "inside" a function would be that they happen between the execution of the entry point of the function and the execution of the exit point of the function. Using this definition it is clear that the solution does not block inside the function or invoke `f` inside the function.

The questioner has also commented that `Await.result` should not be called anywhere. Unfortunately, as explained above, this is not possible because the requirement is to convert an asynchronous result into a synchronous result.

Comment: Awaiting isn't ideal though, as one of the main benefits of Futures is the ability to do things asynchronously.

Comment: No, it is not ideal, but it is required by the question. The result is a synchronous function and you are given an asynchronous function so waiting is the only option. Wrapping a function in a `Future` seems odd, but that is what the question says and who are we to argue? ;)

Comment: How is the non blocking? Doing await!! In convert?

Comment: @RamanMishra `convert` is not blocking, it returns the `Future` immediately (and it does not invoke `f`). Even if it just returned the function it would still not be blocking.

Comment: `g() // Call function` this will block the main thread.
I was expecting solution without Await.result which means by using async await or map/flatmap but problem is, you can not await inside lambda

Comment: @PritamKadam As I understand it you require that `f` cannot be invoked until the function in the result is invoked. But `f` returns a `Future[Int]` and the function in the result returns `Int` so it must wait on that `Future` before it can return the `Int` value, there is no asynchronous option.

Comment: @Tim , yes I agree, there is no asynchronous option.
Initially I thought, below should work but it does not work and it seems there is good reason for that -

`def computeComplexNumber: () ⇒ Future[Int] =
    async { () ⇒
      await(Future {
        println("Computing complex number ...")
        Int.MaxValue
      })
    }`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
 def computeComplexNumber: () => Future[Int] = () =>
  Future {
    delay(4.seconds.fromNow)
    println("Computing complex number ...")
    Int.MaxValue
  }

  def convert(f: () => Future[Int]): Future[() => Int] = {
    f().map( m => () => m)
  }

  def delay(dur:Deadline) = {
    Try(Await.ready(Promise().future, dur.timeLeft))
  }
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51711595/2707792) (could be invisible without access to mod tools).

Comment: And why was it deleted?

Comment: The deleted answer contained the following piece of code: `def convert(f: () ⇒ Future[Int]): Future[() ⇒ Int] = {
  f().map(i => () => i)
}`. The comment that lead to deletion was: *"You execute f() immediately upon entering the convert method. It will print "Computing complex number ..." immediately. Your answer seems to violate [this observation](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3zofjl/why_is_future_totally_unusable/)."* In other words, the impossibility to prevent `Future`s from executing eagerly upon construction is a reddit-meme...